# Understand the meaning of tensor product of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

I am reading Atiyah's Introduction to Commutative Algebra. I have difficulty understanding the meaning of free A module $A^{(M\times N)}$. Here M and N are both A modules. In this book, the free A module is one which is isomorphic to an A module of the form $\oplus_{i\in I}$$M_i$, where each $M_i$ is isomorphic to A. The notion $A^{(I)}$ is used. I think I is the index, then what is the meaning of $A^{(M*N)}$? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually it is meant $A^{|M| \times |N|}$, where $|M|,|N|$ are the underlying sets of $M,N$ and $\times$ is the usual cartesian product of sets. Thus, the free $A$-module $A^{|M| \times |N|}$ consists of formal linear combinations $\sum_{m,n} \lambda_{m,n} (m,n)$, where $\lambda_{m,n} \in A$. (The tensor product results from it by modding out some relations which make the symbols $(m,n)$ behave bilinear.)

Answer (score 2):

First, it is $\;A^{(M\times N)}\;$ , not $\;M*N\;$ . Now, this free $\;A$-module is the set of all formal *sums* $\;\sum a_k(m_k,n_k)\;$ , with $\;a_k=0\;$ for almost all $\;k\;$ , and $\;m_k\in M\;,\;\;n_k\in N\;$ .

Comment: sorry for the tying mistake.

Comment: @user12345, no problem. Try now to correct it in your question.

Comment: I have corrected it.